# Xerces error: org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl 

Tags: jsf, glassfish, jasper-reports, xerces

I'm developing a web application using JSF 2.0, NetBeans 6.9.1, GlassFish Server 3.1, mojarra 2.0.3, and JasperReports 3.7.6. Included in my project library is the jar file "xerces-2.8.0.jar".  This file was imported as part of the JasperReports jar file library.  Whenever I try to deploy, run, or debug my project through NetBeans, I receive this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.
```

After any change in my project my build fails, and I receive the above error, when I try to deploy, run, or debug it.  I have to restart the server and run/debug a second time. I've searched the internet and cannot find a solution to this problem.  I've looked at the jar file in question, and and DTDDVFactoryImpl does indeed extend from DTDDVFactory - I don't know why I'm receiving this error.  While I can eventually get my project running, it would be much nicer if I wasn't receiving this error.

Can anyone please tell me how I can fix this?  Do I need to remove this file from my project library? Do I need to update this file with a newer version/older version?

Comment: I have not.  I thought I had it figured out.  I had multiple Xerxes jar files in the project. I thought by removing the redundant one it would fix things.  I was wrong. It continues to regularly give me this error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you provide your own xerces.jar, you have to do that through the Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism (`java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/path/to/xerces.jar`), you are not allowed to just add it on the classpath (and will sooner or later run into trouble if you do). Let me explain.

JAXP is the [Java API for XML Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing). The creation of JAXP objects (like parsers, XSLT transfomers, DOM Documents) is done through the [factory/factory-method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) so you can plugin a new JAXP implementation (it has to be newer than the one provided in your JRE). Xerces provides (part of) a JAXP implementation and contains endorsed standards (an *endorsed standard* is a Java API defined through a standards process other than the Java Community Process, see the [Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/)). You'll run in all kinds of troubles if you don't use the ESOM.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when using Selenium with Glassfish. I got around it by copying XML jars (`xerces-*, xalan-*, xml-apis*, serialize*`) from `selenium/libs/` to `$AS_HOME/lib/endorsed` (for Glassfish 2) or to `$AS_HOME/glassfish/lib/endorsed` for Glassfish 4.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I added some additional Spring stuff (message-driven POJOs) to my WebLogic app, and now I'm getting this error. WL 10.3.4, Spring 3.0.5. (Yes, I know Spring should be at least up to 3.2.10. I was hoping to get the change in before upgrading Spring.)