# Error while starting the Glassfish server + BIRT dependencies

Tags: jsf, glassfish, birt

I'm trying to deploy a Java web application on a GlassFish server (v 3.1.2) using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1 but I'm always having this Exception:

```
cannot Deploy MetricsReportingProject
Deployment Error for module: MetricsReportingProject: Error occurred during deployment: 
Exception while loading the app : 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: 
Unable to parse document 'bundle://136.0:1/com/sun/faces/jsf-ri-runtime.xml': 
DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Here are my project's dependencies:

- Hibernate 3.4.0 dependencies
- BIRT DE and BIRT Viewer 3.7.1
- JSF 2.0
- PrimeFaces 3.2

The project was working when I'had created it but the problem appears after making some modifications and restarting the server many times.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: the same error is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730103/xerces-error-org-apache-xerces-impl-dv-dtd-dtddvfactoryimpl, and it isn't related to BIRT

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I haven't seen this question before

Answer (score 0):

I hand the same problem.

Glassfish provides a 
- xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
- xml-apis-1.3.04.jar

But in the Birt Lib, they have xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar

I just deleted xercesImpl-2.9.0.jar from Birt Lib and redeployed. It worked fine.