# DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory when use XOM xml library

Tags: java, wildfly

When Deploy the war application in the jboss wildfly getting the following error.

```
DTD factory class org.apache.xerces.impl.dv.dtd.DTDDVFactoryImpl does not extend from DTDDVFactory
```

When I comment the XOM artifact in the pom I can deploy the war without any errors.

How can I fix the deployment error?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6790155/2419292). It will give you the details, but if you provide your own xerces.jar, you have to specify it doing: `java -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/path/to/xerces.jar`.